# Does CMD do CRLF translation?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, console, line-endings

Since Windows uses CRLF as native line endings, one might expect that code like this

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    HANDLE stdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    char* msg = "Line1\nLine2\nLine3\nLine4\nLine5\n";
    DWORD written = 0;
    WriteFile(stdout, msg, strlen(msg), &written, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

would produce the following output:

```
line1
     Line2
          Line3
               Line4
                    Line5
```

But it produces:

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
Line4
Line5
```

Are the LF translated within cmd to also move the cursor to the first line? Because they do not appear to be translated to CRLF when output is redirected to a file (I originally tried WriteConsoleA only to observe that it does not support redirection).

Is it OK to only use LF and not CRLF in cross-platform programs then? Is this behaviour given for all versions of windows or do some of them produce the "staircase" pattern described above?

Comment: @avi You cannot open devices in Windows in some sort of "text" mode. It's always binary. The text/binary distinction is only relevant once you cross what I call the POSIX-barrier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expectations are exactly on target. And you are correct - that isn't what you see.
And @IInspectable is correct that you can't open devices via the Windows CreateFile API in text mode.

And yet, you see what you see.

[If you check out this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/high-level-console-modes), you will find that Windows contains some console mode settings that aren't apparent when you are reading the API function descriptions. In particular, there is an ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT mode that is on by default. When this is on it enables special processing to handle '\n' line endings and other things.

Note that this is for console I/O only. For actual file I/O Windows API calls do no translations. On the other hand, the C library function [fopen](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) allows a file to be opened it text or binary mode. Binary mode does no translation, but text mode enables special handling for `\n` on Windows systems.

I understand that this is also handled similarly for consoles on POSIX systems where "\n" and not "\r\n" is the official standard line ending.

Answer (score 0):

The console standard output buffer has `ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT|ENABLE_WRAP_AT_EOL_OUTPUT` by default.

`\r` alone just returns to the start of the line allowing you to overwrite yourself. `\n` is treated as `\r\n` for unknown reasons (Compatibility? Source portability?). NT4 does it, XP does it, 8 does it and 10 does it.

If you turn off `ENABLE_PROCESSED_OUTPUT` with [`SetConsoleMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) then neither `\r` nor `\n` are special and `WriteFile` will print them as symbols to the console instead.